# Google Maps API v3 not displaying in iFrame with IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer, google-maps, iframe

I have designed a Google map ( http://ozcamps.net/mapboundaries.php ) which works fine by itself however when it is embedded in an iFrame on my works website (a CMS system which I don't have access to, hence the iFrame) it makes the map much smaller (approx 100 pixels by 200 pixels) in IE (I'm using 8) only (fine in FF, Safari, Chrome).

Here's a link to the site with the iFrame: http://www.cbchs.org.au/Our-Sites/Our-Sites/Our-Sites.asp and click the button on the left hand side that says "CHS Boundaries". Any feedback as to why would be greatfully appreciated.

Comment: Note sometimes it does display correctly in IE and other times not. Probably about 50/50. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Place a clear banner to upgrade browser. IE 8 is the new IE 6. There is a website called nomoreie6.com or something like that you can use to get decent CSS and browser choices popup. Or you could use chrome frame if you really believe you actually have IE8 users. Just remember your continued hard work to support obsolete browsers slows evolution ever so slightly lol.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Have to use IE 8 at work as that is what their government designed database needs to display properly! Grr... What worked was doing bad code to my map (ie removing DOCTYPE) to force IE to use Compatability mode and that worked. Poor CMS that we use.

Comment: Frustrating, hope you figure it out! Sorry I couldn't be of more help.